# Export csv file from array

Tags: php, codeigniter, csv

I am using below code for export multidimensional array. I am using CodeIgniter framework(2.1.0 Version)

Problems :

1. I have no any double quotes/single quotes in array but in csv file some fields have double quotes.
2. Each and every csv file give me first two line blanks then contents I can see

CODE :

```
function array_to_csv($array, $download = "") {
    if ($download != "") {
        header('Content-Type: text/csv');
        header('Content-Disposition: attachement; filename="'.$download.
            '"');
        header("Pragma: no-cache");
        header("Expires: 0");
    }

    ob_start();
    $f = fopen('php://output', 'w') or show_error("Can't open php://output");
    $n = 0;
    foreach($array as $line) {
        $line = str_replace('"', '', $line); //Try to resolve first problem but it doesn't work for me.
        $n++;
        if (!fputcsv($f, $line)) {
            show_error("Can't write line $n: $line");
        }
    }
    fclose($f) or show_error("Can't close php://output");
    $str = ob_get_contents();
    ob_end_clean();

    if ($download == "") {
        return $str;
    } else {
        echo $str;
    }
}
```

Comment: Please suggest me if  any  code optimization required in above code to make it faster

Comment: Seems to me your are overcomplicating things a bit. Why all the messing around with ob_start etc? You could just write each line straight to php://output once you had sent your headers. I can't see why you are getting blank lines at the start though

Answer (score 0):

try calling here:

```
$line = str_replace('"', '', $line)
```

trim function.

Comment: Thanks for reply. But this one already i have tried you may see in code.